# WiFi connection acting weird on Linux Mint

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, linux-mint

After I installed Linux Mint on my Laptop, the WiFi connection is having some issues. I can only connect my laptop if the router is in close proximity of a meter or two. Once I start moving it away, after a couple cm it already starts hehaving weirdly. It's disconnecting frequently and sometimes can't detect the wifi anymore. The weird part is, that when I boot my laptop to Windows the WiFi is working very well. So I think Linux Mint has something to do with this.

Comment: Open Driver Manager and check your Wireless adapter if its installed properly.

Comment: theirs nothing in there with label in the bottom "No proprietary are in use". whats that mean?

Comment: If you haven't updated after installing then please run this: **$ sudo apt-get update** command in terminal and update.

Comment: @KinameCole Don't forget $ sudo apt-get upgrade afterwards ...

Comment: @Yamakaja Absolutely, Thanks for reminding me. It's **$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade**.

Comment: i already upgrade and update the system sir. same problem :3

Comment: What card do you use?

Comment: @Orphans where can i find that kind of information in linux sir? totally newbie in linux hehe

Comment: Please run this: **lspci | grep -i wireless** command in Terminal.

Comment: Network Controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Netword Adapter (rev 01) 

thats what i got sir

Comment: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2172044